# How to order by entity property in symfony?

Tags: symfony, dql

I'm trying to get the "demands" of a user.

User can have some demands and a demand have only one user (OneToMany)

This is my User entity (Utilisateur in french) :

```
class Utilisateur extends AbstractEntity implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="ulid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UlidGenerator::class)
     */
    private Ulid $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DemandeTransport::class, mappedBy="utilisateur", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private Collection $demandeTransports;
```

And my demands entity :

```
class DemandeTransport extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="ulid", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=UlidGenerator::class)
     */
    private Ulid $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Utilisateur::class, inversedBy="demandeTransports")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
private Utilisateur $utilisateur;
```

My controller receiving the request :

```
/**
 * @throws Exception
 */
#[Route('/liste_propositions_transporteur', name: 'liste_propositions_transporteur', methods: ['GET'])]
public function listePropositionsTransporteur(Request $request): Response
{
    return match ($request->getMethod()) {
        'GET' => new Response(json_encode(['success' => true, 'data' => $this->propositionsTransportService->handleListePropositionsByUser($this->getUser())])),
        default => new Response(404),
    };
}
```

The service handling the request and retreiving the demands :

```
/**
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @return array
 */
public function handleListePropositionsByUser(UserInterface $user) : array
{
    $propositions = [];
    foreach ($this->propositionTransportRepository->findPropositionsByUtilisateur($user) as $propositionTransport) {
        $propositions[] = DemandeTransportHelper::serializePropositionDemande($propositionTransport);
    }

    return $propositions;
}
```

And the DQL :

```
/**
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @return mixed
 */
public function findPropositionsByUtilisateur(UserInterface $user) : mixed
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.utilisateur = :utilisateur')
        ->setParameters([
            'utilisateur' => $user
        ])
        ->orderBy('p.dateCreation', 'DESC');

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

So :
When i'm doing $utilisateur->getDemandesTransports() : it works by showing me all the demands.

Well, but when I'm trying to get them by DQL (cause I want them orderd by), it returns me 0 results...

Answer (score 3):

Solved by setting the parameter type :

```
->setParameter('utilisateur', $utilisateur->getId(), 'ulid')
```

I'm using ULID (UUID like) on IDs.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/uid.html#working-with-ulids

Answer (score 0):

### With annotations

You can order your data by specifying sorting in your `$demandeTransports` property annotations.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DemandeTransport::class, mappedBy="utilisateur", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateCreation" = "DESC"})
 */
private Collection $demandeTransports;
```

So when you call `$utilisateur->getDemandesTransports()` you will get ordered data.

### With DQL

Also if you still want to use DQL then you should change your query to this as you need to join the `Utilisateur` entity then you can use the desired properties

```
   $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->join('p.utilisateur', 'u')
        ->where('u.utilisateur = :utilisateur')
        ->setParameters([
            'utilisateur' => $user
        ])
        ->orderBy('u.dateCreation', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Even by doing join, it's not working.
When I'm doing $utilisateur->getDemandeTransports()->count() it returns me 35. When I'm doing the DQL, returning me nothing...